# Example on how to use Headers with Confluent Kafka C# library

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to use Headers with the Confluent Kafka C# API but the Message<> template does not have a Headers parameter.  How do you pass in headers to the ProduceAsync method?

Answer (score 2):

```
var header = new Headers();          
header.Add(“key”, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(“value”)) ;     

var config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
};

var _producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(config).Build();
var stringMessage = "Your message";

await _producer.ProduceAsync(topic, new Message<Null, string> { Key = null, Value = stringMessage, Headers = header });
```

Answer (score 1):

I received and answer from GitHub:

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1193#issuecomment-591009614

just set the Headers property in the Message object. I don't think there's an example project that does this, but here it is being done in an integration test: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/test/Confluent.Kafka.IntegrationTests/Tests/Headers.cs#L57